# How can I change the order ID of my categories using SortableJS for jQuery, and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use this JavaScript library called [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) along with jQuery & [jQuery SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/jquery-sortablejs). I have the front-end functionality working, but my issue is trying to get it to work successfully with an AJAX request.

I added `console.log('test')` to see if I could get any results from the AJAX request, but nothing showed. This also makes me believe that my issue has something to do with AJAX.

JavaScript

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-sortablejs@latest/jquery-sortable.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sortable-cards").sortable({
        animation: 350,
        easing: "cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1)",
        stop: function() {
            $.map($(this).find('.col-lg-4'), function(el) {
                var id = el.id;
                var order = $(el).index();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{route('manage.orderCategories')}}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        order: order
                    },
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
<script>
```

Sortable Cards Div in my Blade File

```
<div id="sortable-cards" class="row justify-content-center">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    <div id="{{$category->order}}" class="col-lg-4 col-12 mt-4">
        <div class="card shadow">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3>{{$category->name}}
                <p class="text-muted">{{$category->description}}<p>
                ID: {{$category->id}}<br>
                Order: {{$category->order}}<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Routes

```
Route::post('categories/orderCategories', 'Manage\ManageCategoriesController@orderCategories')->name('orderCategories');
```

Controller

```
public function orderCategories()
{
    $categories = Category::orderBy('order', 'ASC')->get();
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $order = Input::get('order');
    foreach ($categories as $item) {
        return Category::where('id', '=', $id)->update(array('order' => $order));
    }
}
```

The expected result is that when a sortable card is moved it will send an AJAX request to the controller and update the 'order' column in the database. Like I mentioned before the front-end functionality works fine, and there were no error messages present. If you need more information please let me know. Thank you for your help

Comment: Does it send the ajax request? Inspect it on your browser. And where exactly your problem? Controller?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I'll edit the post to display more information, but I added console.log('test') to my JavaScript to see if it was working and it doesn't. I believe it doesn't have anything to do with the controller, but with AJAX. And no, it does not send the AJAX request.

Comment: In the Network tab of inspect check if your ajax request is working. I can see you will get an 419 error as you are not sending CSRF token.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I added CSRF token support but that didn't fix it. And I don't see the AJAX request in the network tab at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I found the solution, instead of using jQuery functions I had to use SortableJS's built-in `toArray()` function to get the updated list of "#sortable-cards". The `toArray()` function uses `data-id` instead of `id` for your div, li, etc. Here's a little more information regarding this [here.](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#toarraystring)

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sortable-cards").sortable({
        animation: 350,
        easing: "cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1)",
        store: {
            set: function (sortable) {
                var order = sortable.toArray();
                console.log(order);
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{route('manage.orderCategories')}}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: order,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('Success');
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        console.log('Fail');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```